# sparse in 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, 3d, sparse-matrix

I have a 3D matrix with 400 rows, 500 columns and the third dimension is 4.
This matrix compose of 1 and 0 but it is not an eye matrix.
How can it be converted to a sparse 3D matrix?

Thank you

Comment: MATLAB does not support 3-D sparse arrays. 400x500x4 is pretty small (especially if you store it as `logical`), so I don't think sparse storage would give you much benefit in any case. The crucial question is: what *operations* do you need to perform on this array?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK matlab does not support 3D sparse arrays, only 2D. You may convert your data to a 4-cell of 2D sparse 400-by-500 matrices.

```
for ii=4:-1:1
    mySp{ii} = sparse( myFull(:,:,ii) );
end
```

See [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) for more information.

Comment: I don't want to use "for". so, I convert every dimension to sparse matrix but when I want to use "cat" for integration these dimensions. I get error.

Comment: @user196345 this is because `cat`-ing the sparse 2D requires Matlab to create spase 3D which is not supported. use the loop to convert into a cell array.

Comment: @rayryeng you know perfectly well what's wrong with it: it's not elegant Matlab-ish ;)

Comment: @Shai :D... well sometimes a `for` loop is merited, such as this case.  I don't see what's wrong with it in this context.

Comment: No, I have the memory and time problem in my code. I want to squeeze it not expand it. it is the reason that I seek sparse. for and loop can elongate my code. Thank you any way.

Comment: @user196345 in that case, you should create your data as a cell of 2D sparse matrices to begin with and not convert it to sparse as a post processing.